# Search a Numpy Array based on array index

Tags: python, search, numpy, conditional-statements

I have a 2D numpy array and I would like to change some of the elements based on two criteria:
The first criteria is a condition.
The second criteria is based on the index of the array (row and column number)

For instance take the following code,

```
import numpy as np
#Create an 8x8 array
A = np.arange(64).reshape(8,8)
condition = (A %2 ==0)
B = np.where(condition,0,A)
print B
```

This works but I don't want to apply the condition on the entire domain of A. I only want to apply the condition on a user-specified range of cells, say the first three rows and first two columns.

How can I modify my code to accomplish this ?

Thanks!
PK

***Edit : Updated code based on MathDan's suggestion***

```
import numpy as np

#Create an 8x8 array
A = np.arange(64).reshape(8,8)
#Create boolean conditional array
condition = np.zeros_like(A,dtype='bool')
#Enforce condition on the first 4X4 matrix
condition[0:4, 0:4] = (A[0:4, 0:4] % 2 ==0)
B = np.where(condition,0,A)
print B
```

Comment: Thanks Mathdan. That seems so easy and intuitive that I am kicking myself for not thinking of it.    `condition = zeros_like(A,dtype='bool')  condition[0:2][0:1] = (A[0:2][0:1] % 2 ==0)  B = np.where(condition,0,A)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (for example):

```
condition = np.zeros_like(A, dtype='bool')
condition[0:2, 0:1] = (A[0:2, 0:1] % 2 ==0)
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work for me. Maybe I am missing something. condition[0:2][0:1] = (A[0:2][0:1] % 2 ==0) followed by C = np.where(condition,0,A) give me : shape mismatch error

Comment: Right, sorry. I left out a line: condition = zeros_like(A,dtype='bool')

Comment: `A[0:2][0:1]` is not the same as `A[0:2, 0:1]`, you want the second one. The fist one will index in the first dimension twice.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, Bi Rico. I incorporated it into the answer.